# Complete block is not coming in navigation bar?

Tags: css

I have write following code to make a navigation bar following [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7yUhJ/).

```
<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="#">home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">home</a></li>

</ul>
#nav li
{
float:left;
margin-right:13px;
margin-top:25px;
border-left:1px dashed gray;
}
#nav a
{
display:block;
margin:20px 10px;
}
#nav a:hover
{
color:red;
}
```

On hovering complete red color on block is not showing up I want some thing like this 
[image]

But red color is just showing on link not on complete block. Help me out in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#nav a:hover
{
color:red;
}
```

The `color` property is for specifying the *text* color. The reason that only the text color is changing is because this is all you've asked for. If you want the *background* color to change, you need to specify `background-color`:

```
#nav a:hover
{
  background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks yes this will help alot to me thanks from this i could proceed further thanks again.